# Matching parameterized types in Rust

Tags: types, pattern-matching, rust

In a Rust program, I have a use case where I want to print either a number, or a pipe-separated vector of numbers, thus this simple wrapper enum:

```
pub enum OneOrMore<T> {
  One(T),
  More(Vec<T>)
}
```

which works fine. But then I wanted to move the format logic into the `OneOrMore` type, so I tried:

```
impl<T: Show> Show for OneOrMore<T> {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result {
    match self {
      One(x) => x.fmt(f),
      More(xs) => /* vec_join(xs, "|") or whatever */,
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `impl` is parameterized, it's expecting a `One<T>` but my code is describing a `One<_>`. Problem is I can't figure out where to put the type parameter inside the match arms. The [syntax guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions) doesn't give an example of matching on parameterized types, `fmt` itself doesn't accept a type parameter, and all my blind guesses (`One(x: T)`, `One<T>(x)`, etc) aren't valid Rust. Any ideas where I should indicate the type of the match arms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `match` expression, `self` is of type `&OneOrMore<T>`, but the arm patterns are of type `OneOrMore<T>`; i.e. you're matching on references, but the arms are not references.

You can change the patterns to references:

```
impl<T: Show> Show for OneOrMore<T> {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
    match self {
      &One(ref x) => x.fmt(f),
      &More(ref xs) => /* ... */,
    }
  }
}
```

or you can avoid having to repeat `&` by dereferencing `self` instead:

```
impl<T: Show> Show for OneOrMore<T> {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
    match *self {
      One(ref x) => x.fmt(f),
      More(ref xs) => /* ... */,
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in both cases, we need to add the `ref` keyword on the `x` and `xs` bindings to create references to the `OneOrMore`'s interior. In other words, without `ref`, `x` and `xs` would be of type `T`; with `ref`, they are of type `&T`. Without `ref`, the compiler complains that we're trying to move a value out of the `OneOrMore`, which isn't allowed through a borrow.

Comment: Thanks, I completely misinterpreted the compiler error this time.

Comment: Standard Rust style is `match *foo { Bar => () }` rather than `match foo { &Bar => () }`, incidentally, though that can’t remain true for cases where the expression being matched on is a tuple, like `match (self, other) { (&Foo, &Foo) => () }`.